# addClass "input-invalid" to input doesn't show until I click outside the input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a zipcode field and on `keyup` I do an ajax call. If there are no zipcodes available then I want to add the class "input-invalid". But the problem is the red bordered validation doesn't show-up until I click somewhere **outside** of the input field. Is it possible to add the class when the cursor is still in the input field?

Jquery:

```
$("#zipcode").on("keyup", function (event) {

       $(this).removeClass('input-invalid');
       // some validations here

        $.ajax({
            url: '../Service/SearchByZipCodes',
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                zipcode: this.value.substring(0, 3)
            },
            contenttype: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (response) {
               if (response.Results.length > 0) {
                    //DO somethings
                }
                else {
                    results = [];
                    $(".autocomplete-suggestions").hide();
                    $("#zipcode").addClass("input-invalid");
                }
            },
            error: function (err) {
                errorAlert("An error occurred");
            }
        });
```

CSS

```
.input-invalid {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 12px red;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 12px red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px red;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Bootstrap css

```
.form-control:focus {
   border-color: #66afe9;
   outline: 0;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
   box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: can you share the css

Comment: It may be because the AJAX request is taking some time to complete.

Comment: maybe css rule for `.invalid` is overwritten by another css for input itself, when on focus.. can you find any `:focus` css rule

Comment: That could be the problem. will check.

Comment: Your posted code would work as expected. You have to provide all relevant code to replicate your issue, what about a jsFiddle?!

Comment: @NaeemShaikh Found the culprit bootstrap class. How do I override this? I don't want to comment it.

Comment: I think making an ajax request for every single keyup is really over the top. By the time you type in 10 characters your server gets spammed and can't complete it very fast. You should build in a timer that starts running on keyup and saves the last value of the field, if it didn't change by the end of the timer, you should make your ajax request

Comment: @adiga.. see the answer below

Comment: @Pinki I have ommitted some code here. Zipcode's max length is 5 digits(US). And I do ajax call only if there are minimum 3 characters and send only the first 3 characters of the string, then filter it client side for the 4th and 5th digits, if any. If they change the first 3 letters only another call is made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my comments above:

> maybe css rule for .invalid is overwritten by another css for input
>   itself, when on focus.. can you find any :focus css rule

In this case bootstrap is overwriting the `box-shadow` property for `.form-control`

```
     .form-control:focus {
          border-color: #66afe9;
          outline: 0;
         -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
```

you can override this if you really dont want to comment it out, like this

```
    .input-invalid.form-control:focus {
              border://whatever you want;
             -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 12px red;
             -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 12px red;
             box-shadow: 0 0 12px red;
          }
```